# XMLHTTPRequest not working on browsers except IE

Tags: xmlhttprequest

I am trying to get some data using the WCF Rest based service.

This is my code.

jQuery.support.cors = true;

```
        $.ajax({
            url: http://localhost:2545/Service/GetData,
            data: JSON.stringify(temp),
            beforeSend: function (xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); },
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "Json",
            crossdomain: true,
            success: function (result) { ProximitySucceeded(result) },
            error: function (result) { debugger; ServiceFailed(result) }
        });
```

My website is running on http://localhost:1600 and service is on http://localhost:2545.

Its working on IE fine. But on chrome/ firefox /safari returning this error 
"Origin http://localhost:1600 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin."

Please help as the service is not being accessed from any browser other than IE.

Thanks.
Mohit.

Comment: Why are you trying to use `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` as a **request** header?

Comment: Agreed, Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not something that should be set on the request, it should be set by the server on the response. Since you are making the request from localhost to localhost, can you use Wireshark to get at trace of the actual HTTP requests being made?

Answer (score 0):

i think this may be counting as cross site scripting and being denied because the different port makes it a different domain.

to get round this you may need to setup a proxy.

hope that helps